# PostgreSQL: Adjust foreign keys on children to remove duplication in parents

Tags: postgresql

I've taken over a project which has some existing data in PostgreSQL that needs to be adjusted. Specifically, in a system where Teams belong to Leagues, I need to remove duplicated names from the leagues table. In preparation for this I need to adjust foreign keys in the teams table such that they no longer make reference to the leagues that will be deleted. Note that it doesn't matter which leagues I delete and which I keep as long as I keep exactly one for each distinct league name.

It's easier to explain with an example. Below we can see that "Red Squirrels" and "Green Monkeys" both belong to the league "Western League", currently though there are two rows with the name "Western League". I need delete rows in the leagues table such that league names are unique but first I need to alter the `league_ids` in the teams table so that they reference the league row that will not be deleted.

```
  leagues
  id  | name
  1   | "Western League"
  2   | "Western League"
  3   | "Eastern League"

  teams
  id  | league_id | name
  1   | 1         | "Red Squirrels"
  2   | 2         | "Green Monkeys"
  3   | 3         | "Blue Ducks"
```

In the simple example above the goal would be to change the league_id on "Green Monkeys" to 1 so then both "Red Squirrels" and "Green Monkeys" reference the same league. After that no teams reference the second "Western League" league and it can be deleted. We have too much data to make the changes row-by row though.

Really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows which league should be replaced by another one:

```
select id, min(id) over (partition by name) as correct_id
from leagues

 id | correct_id 
----+------------
  3 |          3    -- ok
  1 |          1    -- ok
  2 |          1    -- needs replacing
(3 rows)
```

If we join this with teams we can select teams which need to be corrected:

```
select t.id as team_id, correct_id
from (
    select id, min(id) over (partition by name) as correct_id
    from leagues
    ) l
join teams t on t.league_id = l.id
where t.league_id <> correct_id

 team_id | correct_id 
---------+------------
       2 |          1
(1 row)
```

Use the last query to update teams:

```
update teams
set league_id = correct_id
from (
    select t.id as team_id, correct_id
    from (
        select id, min(id) over (partition by name) as correct_id
        from leagues
        ) l
    join teams t on t.league_id = l.id
    where t.league_id <> correct_id
    ) c
where id = team_id
returning team_id, name, correct_id

 team_id |      name       | correct_id 
---------+-----------------+------------
       2 | "Green Monkeys" |          1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi Klin, I really appreciate you taking the time to provide such a detailed and accurate answer. This worked perfectly and also taught me a lot. Thanks again and have a great day!